# Bevel does not work after solidify

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm applying a bevel to a plane, solidify and bevel after solidify, but the bevel doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

What I'm trying to do is this:

[image]

What I want to do is to transform the plane into a cylinder through the modifiers and with that make an insert. Would this be logical or is it better to use a cylinder?

But look what happens when I increase the amount of bevel:

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to make a speaker, following what I'm learning in a course.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is not the _Solidify Modifier_ but the fact that you're beveling the vertices at first. And how large is your object? The vertices are beveled 1.166 m with 20 segments... that sounds like overkill to me.

Comment: Plug a weld modifier after the 1 st bevel and before the solidify. The first bevel creates duplicate vertices on the same spot

Comment: Is there anything else you've done to the mesh? Even if the Solifdify would keep the second Bevel from working, the object doesn't even seem to have the vertices beveled - and that can't be the fault of the Solidify.

Comment: Now that I looked closer, your second screenshot suggests you want to bevel the cylinder object - but the first screenshot shows you've selected an object called "Plane.001", and this has the mdifiers. Is Plane.001 the cylinder (it doesn't look selected in the 3D viewport)?

Comment: if the above comments doesn't help you, please provide your blend file